# webkit transition rule not working at all in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions

I have the following CSS transition rule:

```
.headroom {
    -ms-transition: transform 200ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: transform 200ms linear;
    transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
```

But latest version of Safari (8.0.6) is not detecting the transition rule:

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I had to add prefix like followed:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms linear;
```

Annoyance.